# Acronis Backup Advanced 11.5 for Citrix XenServer 6.5 installation issues

Tags: backup, xenserver, citrix, acronis

We are trying to deploy Acronis Backup Advanced for Citrix XenServer on a running pool of XenServer's.

The documentation of the product isn't quite clear about the procedure of the installation and the support of the vendor wasn't able to help on the installation of the product.

As for as I know, it requires an SSH connection to the host from the Acronis Management Server software, and I've confirmed this on SSH attempts from the AMS machine:

```
Jun 25 22:39:37 xenserver1 sshd[30317]: Received disconnect from 10.7.0.250: 11: Bye
Jun 25 19:39:37 xenserver1 sshd[30318]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for acronis.local.iq.ufrj.br failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Jun 25 19:39:37 xenserver1 sshd[30318]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:account): requirement "user ingroup IQ-UFRJ\xencenter+pool+admin" not met by user "root"
Jun 25 19:39:37 xenserver1 sshd[30318]: Accepted password for root from 10.7.0.250 port 54424 ssh2
Jun 25 19:39:37 xenserver1 sshd[30318]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jun 25 19:39:37 xenserver1 sshd[30318]: [module:pam_lsass]pam_sm_open_session failed [login:root][error code: 40081]
Jun 25 19:39:37 xenserver1 sshd[30327]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for acronis.local.iq.ufrj.br failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Jun 25 19:39:37 xenserver1 sshd[30327]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:account): requirement "user ingroup IQ-UFRJ\xencenter+pool+admin" not met by user "root"
Jun 25 19:39:37 xenserver1 sshd[30327]: Accepted password for root from 10.7.0.250 port 54425 ssh2
Jun 25 19:39:37 xenserver1 sshd[30327]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jun 25 19:39:37 xenserver1 sshd[30327]: [module:pam_lsass]pam_sm_open_session failed [login:root][error code: 40081]
Jun 25 19:39:37 xenserver1 sshd[30327]: subsystem request for sftp
Jun 25 19:39:37 xenserver1 sshd[30327]: Received disconnect from 10.7.0.250: 11: Bye
Jun 25 19:39:37 xenserver1 sshd[30327]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
Jun 25 19:39:37 xenserver1 sshd[30318]: Received disconnect from 10.7.0.250: 11: Bye
Jun 25 19:39:37 xenserver1 sshd[30318]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
Jun 25 19:39:37 xenserver1 sshd[30327]: [module:pam_lsass]pam_sm_close_session error [error code:40081]
Jun 25 19:39:37 xenserver1 sshd[30318]: [module:pam_lsass]pam_sm_close_session error [error code:40081]
```

The problem, is on the next step: it complains about no components installed and I think it should upload the packages for installation on this part, but the next screen only shows greyed out options and we are unable to continue the installation.

Here's an screenshot of the problem:
[image: Acronis Backup Screen]

Has anyone deployed Acronis Backup successfully with Citrix XenServer?

Thanks in advance,